# Is it possible to optimize a SELECT COUNT(*) query using a filtered index as a hint to achieve constant speed?

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization, indexing, sql-server-2012, filtered-index

I'd like to count all the Orders that are not urgent and whose order status = 1 (shipped).

This should be a very simple query to optimize. I'd like to put a simple filtered index on the Orders table to cover this query to make it a constant time/O(1) operation. However, when I look at the query plan, it looks like it's using a Index Scan which doesn't make sense. Ideally, this query should just returning the number of items in the index.

The table look like this (simplified to get to the essence):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsUrgent] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )
```

I've created this filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Orders_ShippedNonUrgent ON Orders(Id) WHERE IsUrgent = 0 AND Status = 1;
```

Now, when I do this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE IsUrgent = 0 AND Status = 1
```

I see that the query plan is using IX_Orders_ShippedNonUrgent, but it's doing an Index Scan and performing around 200 reads across the ~150,000 rows in Orders.

Is it possible to always have this query run in constant time assuming the filtered index is kept up to date? Ideally, it should only perform 1 read to get the size of the index.

If I switch to a non-filtered index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Orders_IsUrgentStatus ON Orders(IsUrgent, Status);
```

The query plan uses an Index Seek, but still performs many more reads than should be necessary to answer this simple query.

**UPDATE**

I'm able to do this

```
SELECT TOP 1 rows FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
ON i.name = 'IX_Orders_ShippedNonUrgent'
AND i.object_id = p.object_id
AND i.index_id = p.index_id
```

and get the result in 9 reads but it seems like there should be a much easier and less brittle way of using the simple COUNT(*) query.

Comment: Does anything change if you change count(*) to read count(id)? Alternatively, have you considered materialized view?

Comment: Switching from COUNT(*) to COUNT(Id) has no effect on the plan or reads. Checking on the view...

Comment: I did a "CREATE VIEW VW_Orders_Test AS SELECT COUNT(1) As Count FROM Orders WHERE IsUrgent = 0 AND Status = 1" and it had the same query plan and reads

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have included [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). View needs clustered unique index.

Comment: Do you mean to create an indexed view instead of the filtered index?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ment. For some reason I learned the feature by the name `materialized view`.

Comment: I did CREATE VIEW [dbo].VW_Orders_Test WITH SCHEMABINDING AS SELECT Id,Status,IsUrgent FROM [dbo].Orders WHERE Status = 1 AND IsUrgent = 0
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_VW_Orders_Test ON VW_Orders_Test (Status, IsUrgent, Id) and it did a clustered index scan and the reads went up

Comment: One more idea and I'm done - what if your indexed view select count_big(*) only? And then you retrieve the value as `select cnt from VW_Orders_Test (noexpand)`?

Comment: That created a clustered index scan on the indexed views clustered index but resulted in only 2 reads! Nice. Any way to get this level of performance without resorting to the indexed view would be most appreciated as I have several queries like this and am generating them from Entity Framework. It seems like the query optimizer should be smart enough to see this approach and the filtered index approach as the same and get me down to 2 or less reads in either case.

Comment: `the query optimizer should be smart enough to see this approach and the filtered index approach as the same`. They aren't the same. The indexed view has the `COUNT` precalculated the filtered index doesn't (or actually an approximate value is stored in `sys.partitions` but that is not guaranteed accurate and never used to answer `COUNT` queries).

Comment: @MartinSmith Shouldn't the row size of the index be known in advance? I would have thought that the optimizer would have noticed it could just take that row count since the predicates/WHERE matches

Comment: The index just store keys and pointers. No count information is present anywhere in the index structure. You need to count the index rows to find that out. The metadata in `sys.partitions` is not guaranteed to be accurate anyway [Indicates the approximate number of rows in this partition.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012.aspx) and couldn't really be used even if it was as there could be multiple concurrent transactions all with uncommitted changes to the table but there is only one value stored so the `COUNT` result would not be transactionally consistent.

Comment: ... Except if every DML statement affecting the index blocked each other waiting to update the count. If you need that behaviour you can create an indexed view.

Comment: What time are you getting?  Count on  150,000 rows even with an index seek should be less than 1/10 second.

Comment: @Blam I'm doing a similar type of query for 2 tables and was getting an aggregate count of ~15ms when I was expecting it to be less than 1 ms since it was so simple (on an SSD) and was baffled by all the reads and why it was doing a scan instead of a seek given the filtered index that perfectly matched the predicates. With MartinSmith 's help, I think my understanding of indexes was slightly off

Comment: @JeffMoser: If you are still interested in this question, my suggestion is to flag this (and ask for migration to DBA.SE). I would vote to close (and migrate) but the question is "too old" and I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what I'm wanting isn't possible. The best answer was left in the comments by [Nikola Markovinović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231866/nikola-markovinovic) which is to forget about the filtered index and use an indexed view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].vw_Orders_TotalShippedNonUrgent WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS TotalOrders 
  FROM dbo.Orders WHERE IsUrgent = 0 AND Status = 1;
```

with

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_vw_Orders_TotalShippedNonUrgent ON vw_Orders_TotalShippedNonUrgent(TotalOrders);
```

This forces creating views and their index for each summary statistic that I want as well as rewriting the query to ask the view instead of the simple approach, but it is fast at only 2 reads.

I'll leave this question open for awhile in case anyone has a simpler approach that's just as fast.